# how to use the CSS ::theme selector

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

ive started making a HTML/CSS/Vanilla JS web component library, and so far everything is going great.
im using the typical ::part and all that, but i stumbled accros ::theme selector aswell, which is supposed to give quick access to styling without a creator having to set up more than necesarry.

problem is, i - whatever ive tried - can't seem to the get the ::theme selector work, is there anyone who can help me out ?

screendump is from https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/, tried following but i dont know if this selector is still experimental ?, it would really make styling my components alot easier if it worked !

[image: this screen is from following link that talks about it]

Comment: I can't find `::theme()` in MDN, or caniuse.com, so I'm going to guess no browser supports it. The page you linked to also says "As mentioned before, this spec is still in the works and we don’t have a shim that you can use in production."

Comment: @gunr2171 it is a selector that is part of [Shadow DOM Framework](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom)

Comment: i just found that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part are linking to it aswell at the bottom -> https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md
not sure what to make of it though, is it still  a work in progress ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Sadly the ::theme selector did not make the cut

After a lot of digging, I've found the ::theme selector was a proposal which didn't get implemented 
Although mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part at the bottom under "See also".
I then found this explainer issue that was closed, confirming that the ::theme did not make the cut https://github.com/fergald/docs/issues/4 
The ::theme selector is therefor also not in the docs of CSS Shadow parts as of the CSS W3C Editors draft from 15th September 2020, see it below: 
 https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts/

I don't know if anyone will pick up the torch and implement this pseudo selector, but i surely do hope so, as i would see it frequently used, at least in my needs.

Hope this question and answer will help someone else out and not spend tons of time going down this rabbit-hole :)